# Merge two dataframe in pandas with different size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find a method to join two dataframes in pandas in an elegant way without doing grafted loops. The first dataframe appears with the following structure and a "week_of_year" column

[image]

The second smallest dataframe, possesses the maximum value recorded in that week

[image]

What I would like to do is to merge the two dataframes so that in the first dataframe the value 34 appears repeatedly for all the columns that have value 12 and so on

Comment: don't aggregate & merge.  use `groupby` + `transform`. [link document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just merge them (`df1` is your first DataFrame, `df2` is the second one):

```
df1.merge(df2, how="left")
```

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) you can find the documentation of the `merge` method.